# How to highlight newly added item to CollectionView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Iam using Xamarin forms.I have CollectionView in Xamarins showing List of Tickets.I want to highlight new rows whenever its inserted.Like flashing or blinking the row with red background say for 5 seconds.After 5 seconds it should be normal row. Clients will add rows in real time using SignalR.

Edit : I am adding more code.Now its highlighting successfully whenever new item is added to CollectionView.But not always.After few inserts it stops firing frame1_ChildAdded event.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"  
                            
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            SelectionMode="None"
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset"  
            >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        
                        <Frame x:Name="frame1" BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" Padding="3" Margin="0,0,0,5" HasShadow="False"  CornerRadius="10" ChildAdded="frame1_ChildAdded">
                                <Grid HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lb_TicketNumber" Text="{Binding TicketNumber}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DeskName}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ServiceNameEng}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>
```

Code Behind

```
private async void frame1_ChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame fr = e.Element.FindByName("frame1") as Frame;
            fr.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            await fr.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(1, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(1, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(1, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(1, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
            await fr.FadeTo(1, 500);
            fr.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        }
```

Comment: You could try to let your CollectionView to select the last item when adding new data to the ViewModel and make a timer for 5 seconds,then deselect later.

Comment: That will not be enough.Same time multiple records can be inserted. If multiple rows inserted same time i need to highlight them for some seconds

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
It looks like the CollectionView has bugs. I tried it with my Custom BindableStackLayout and it worked:

```
public class BindableStackLayout : StackLayout
{
 public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
 BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(BindableStackLayout), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

public object SelectedItem
{
  get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
  set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
{
  get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(BindableStackLayout),
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
      try
      {
        if (newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged observableCollection)
          observableCollection.CollectionChanged += (coll, arg) =>
             {
               var control = (BindableStackLayout)bindable;
               switch (arg.Action)
               {
                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                   foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                   {
                     var itemTemplate = control.ItemDataTemplate.CreateContent() as View;
                     itemTemplate.BindingContext = v;
                     var gr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                     gr.Tapped += Gr_Tapped;
                     itemTemplate.GestureRecognizers.Add(gr);

                     itemTemplate.Scale = 0;

                     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                     {

                       control.Children.Insert(arg.NewStartingIndex, itemTemplate);
                       Task.Run(async () =>
                       {
                         await itemTemplate.ScaleTo(1, 250U, Easing.CubicInOut);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(1, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(1, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(1, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(1, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(0.2, 500);
                         await itemTemplate.FadeTo(1, 500);
                       });


                     });

                   }
                   break;
                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                   foreach (var v in arg.OldItems)
                   {
                     var element = v;
                     var elementToDelete = control.Children.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BindingContext == element);
                     var index = control.Children.IndexOf(elementToDelete);

                     control.Children[index].ScaleTo(0, 250U, Easing.Linear);
                     control.Children.RemoveAt(index);
                     //control.ForceLayout();
                   }
                   break;
                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                   //Do your stuff
                   break;
                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                   var item = control.Children.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BindingContext == arg.OldItems[0]);
                   if (item != null) item.BindingContext = arg.NewItems[0];
                   break;
               }
             };
      }
      catch (System.Exception e)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
      }
      ((BindableStackLayout)bindable).InsertItems();
    });

private static async void Gr_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender is VisualElement view)
  {
    var saveBackgroundcolor = view.BackgroundColor;

    view.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;

    if (view.Parent is BindableStackLayout bindableStackLayout)
    {
      bindableStackLayout.SelectedItem = view.BindingContext;
    }

    await Task.Delay(500);

    view.BackgroundColor = saveBackgroundcolor;
  }
}

public DataTemplate ItemDataTemplate
{
  get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemDataTemplateProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ItemDataTemplateProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemDataTemplateProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemDataTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BindableStackLayout));


void InsertItems()
{
  if (ItemsSource == null) return;
  Children.Clear();
  foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
  {
    var itemTemplate = ItemDataTemplate.CreateContent() as View;
    itemTemplate.BindingContext = item;
    var gr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    gr.Tapped += Gr_Tapped;
    itemTemplate.GestureRecognizers.Add(gr);
    Children.Add(itemTemplate);
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip.I edited my question after adding your code in little different way.But there is another issue i am facing as mentioned in edited question.Please go through it

Comment: After few inserts it stops firing animation.Same as my original issue..